# Undefined reference to

Tags: c++, undefined

Here is my code for tripe.cpp

```
//tripe.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include "tripe.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

Tripe::Tripe()
{
    trie = new Trie();
    heap = NULL;
}
```

This is my trie.h:

```
//trie.h

#ifndef TRIE_H
#define TRIE_H

#include <string>
#include "heapNode.h"
#include "trienode.h"


class Trie
{
    Tnode* root_node;
    public:
        Trie();
        ~Trie();
```

the compiler says:
 In function `Tripe::Tripe()':
tripe.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`Trie::Trie()'

how is that not clearly defined? I included the header fie!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `trie.cpp` file, which actually defines the constructor `Trie()` , then you need to compile that file and link it with your application.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linker error. Do you have a definition ([not just a declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e5kx78b.aspx)) of this constructor?

Comment: Sorry I just edited it.  I accidentally put the tripe.h instead of the trie.h. This is my definition 

    Trie::Trie()
    {
      rootNode = new Tnode();
    }

Comment: Yes, I see that you have a declaration (`class Trie{ ... }`) but you need a definition (where you specify the code for each function). This should be in a separate cpp file and linked to your compiled tripe.cpp file.

Comment: Also, I am getting this error for every function I am using, but I have included all of the .h files in the tripe.cpp, which is where all of the errors are coming from.

Comment: Whenever you call a function the compiler will look in the header file, see the **declaration**, check the return type and arguments to see if they match, throwing errors if they do not. The linker (which is what is giving you errors here) will point the function calls you have made to the **definitions** of the functions in another compiled cpp file. These definitions contain the code that is executed when the function is called. Either you have not written a trie.cpp file or it does not contain a definition of `Trie::Trie(){...}` or you have not specified its location to the linker.